# Is Lucy fueled with hydrazine and liquid oxygen?

Tags: liquid-fuel, hypergolics, lucy-asteroid-mission

> On Sept. 18, propulsion engineers finished filling Lucy’s fuel tanks
> with approximately 1,600 pounds (725 kilograms) of liquid hydrazine
> and liquid oxygen, which make up 40% of the mass of the spacecraft.
> The fuel will be used for precise maneuvers that will propel Lucy to
> its asteroid destinations on schedule, while the solar arrays – each
> the width of a school bus – will recharge the batteries that will
> power spacecraft instruments.

Source: https://www.scientiststudy.com/2021/09/nasas-lucy-mission-prepares-for-launch.html

> The probe is fuelled by 725 kg of liquid hydrazine and liquid oxygen,
> making up 40% of its mass.

Source: https://spacewatch.global/2021/10/nasas-lucy-to-probe-trojan-asteroids/

[image]

Source: https://english.lokmat.com/technology/nasas-lucy-mission-prepares-for-launch-to-trojan-asteroids/

**Is Lucy really fueled with cryogenic liquid oxygen?**

The combination of hydrazine and dinitrogen tetroxide is used very often for space probes that should work for several years requiring fuels that are liquid at non cryogenic temperatures.

Comment: Since this is the sole supporting source for your [other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55270/12102), I guess we should assume it to be *authoritative* :-)

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of the unanswered https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49947/where-can-i-read-about-lucys-complete-propulsion-system

Comment: BTW, the solar panels aren't "the width of a school bus" either, but have a 3 times larger diameter (7.3m).

Comment: Do we need a "misleading/wrong press release" tag? There have been several questions about them.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33951/40257

Comment: You don't need to add all these sources, just link to the original press release: https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-lucy-mission-prepares-for-launch-to-trojan-asteroids

Comment: related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33970/40257

Comment: Nammo (makers of LEROS series engines) claims Lucy uses the [LEROS-1c](https://www.nammo.com/product/leros-1c/). This engine uses "MON / Hydrazine" as propellant according to [datasheet](https://www.nammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/2021-Nammo-Westcott-Liquid-Engine-LEROS1C.pdf)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 The datasheet does specify the oxidiser MON, a solution of nitric oxide (NO) in dinitrogen tetroxide/nitrogen dioxide (N2O4 and NO2). So liquid oxygen is wrong. What about writing an answer?

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Where did you find this claim?

Comment: @asdfex in the datasheet it claims this